# Why is the `prototype` field of the built-in Object function treated differently in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Conceptually, I thought if an object `obj` is an instance of a "class/constructor" `Constructor`, then `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Constructor.prototype`.

This pattern works for almost all "types", including most built-in functions:

```js
Object.getPrototypeOf(Boolean.prototype) === Object.prototype
true
Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype) === Object.prototype
true
Object.getPrototypeOf(String.prototype) === Object.prototype
true
```

But this does not seem to apply to the built-in function `Object`.

```js
Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype) === Object.prototype
false                // <----------------- Why?
```

Well, `Object.prototype` intuitively is an object too. But the above pattern does not apply. Did I miss anything?

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype)` returns `null`.

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah I noticed that, but my question is why it is defined in such an inconsistent way？

Comment: You're asking why the prototype of `Object.prototype` is not `Object.prototype`? I'll let you think about this for a moment. I am going to give you two words as hints: chicken and egg.

Comment: @VLAZ Ah....right. Conceptually the prototype of an object must be **ANOTHER DIFFERENT** object! My previous understanding is indeed flawed. This rule wins over the instance-constructor pattern mentioned in my question. To break the chicken-egg-loop and respect this rule, the prototype of `Object.prototype` is specially treated that my pattern fails to capture. Is that correct?

Comment: If the prototype is *another* object, then what's *that object's* prototype? And then *that object's*. It's infinite regression. Realistically, the engine *can* construct `Object.prototype` and afterwards assign that object as the prototype of itself. But...what's the point? You just get an circular link of prototypes where `a.prototype` is still `a`. At best that serves no purpose at all. At worse, it hinders walking up the prototype chain (as you now have to stop when the next object up is the current object). So, `null` is just a mildly useful marker for "top of prototype chain".

Answer (score 0):

I think result of `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype)` that saying *`Object.prototype` doesn't have a prototype* is a well explanation.

```js
const protoOf_true = Object.getPrototypeOf(true);
console.log(Boolean.prototype === protoOf_true);

const protoOf_Boolean = Object.getPrototypeOf(protoOf_true);
console.log(Object.prototype === protoOf_Boolean);

const protoOf_Object = Object.getPrototypeOf(protoOf_Boolean);
console.log(null === protoOf_Object);
```

Comment: Right. But my question is *why* it doesn't have a prototype. (Or put differently, having null as its prototype.)

Comment: @wlnirvana there is a place where prototype chain ends. That's the place where prototype is equal to null. Read the doc - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain